# Odoo v10: How to display the email of the current logged in user in a form?

Tags: forms, email, session, authentication, odoo-10

In order to get current session user id we use: `request.session.uid`.

For example in an input type it's like this:

`<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="current_user_id" readonly="1" t-att-value="request.session.uid"></input>`

But how to get the email address instead of id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the current user in request.env.user object and refer to users's email field like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="current_user_email" readonly="1" t-att-value="request.env.user.email"></input>
```

Br,

Veikko